# Enable to write in Virtualbox's shared folder

Tags: mount, virtualbox, lubuntu

I have a `Lubuntu 15.10` VM installed  in a Windows 7  host and running with `Virtualbox Version 5.0.14` .

I've created a permanent shared folder in Virtualbox's machine configuration and set it to be automatically mounted and unchecked the read only option

When I try to copy a directory to this mounted folder I get this error message for every file in the source directory

```
root@foo /v/w/h/# sudo cp -r . /media/sf_C_DRIVE
cp: impossible de créer le fichier standard «/media/sf_C_DRIVE/./.gitignore»: Erreur de protocole
cp: impossible de créer le fichier standard «/media/sf_C_DRIVE/./composer.json»: Erreur de protocole
cp: impossible de créer le fichier standard «/media/sf_C_DRIVE/./composer.lock»: Erreur de protocole
cp: impossible de créer le fichier standard «/media/sf_C_DRIVE/./composer.phar»: Erreur de protocol
```

Which is literary translated to `impossible to create the standard file /media/sf_C_DRIVE/./.gitignore : protocole error`

Any Idea about how can I fix this ?

## Edit 1

My user is already in the `vboxsf` group

```
root@jerbi /m/sf_C_DRIVE# groups jerbi
jerbi : jerbi adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxsf
```

So it seems to be a mount error as I can't remount the folder getting this error

```
/sbin/mounpt.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed this by creating a new mount point in `/home/username/share`

```
# ln -s /media/sf_C_DRIVE /home/username/share
# chown username:username /home/username/share
# exit
```

Then I restarted the system and run `chmod` to the new directory in the startup

```
$ chmod 777 ~/share
```

Answer (score 4):

The usual problem is that you must add yourself into the `vboxsf` group in `/etc/group` on the guest machine. Try the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf $USER
```

Followed by logging out and then re-login.

Comment: Tried this .. same output

Comment: So the problem can be on the Windows side: what is the name of the shared folder?  The name can be an issue sometimes and on your Windows Host should preferably be a sub-folder...

Comment: try to move a file from one dir to another in the windows command prompt, it might say Access is denied, indicating a windows problem.

Answer (score 1):

The host os and host device formatting can cause this issue.  My host os is Mac OS,  I have mounted shared folders which are APFS and exFat.

```
sudo mount -o defaults,uid=1000,gid=$(getent group docker | cut -d: -f3) -t vboxsf mcs /media/sf_mcs
sudo mount -o defaults,uid=1000,gid=$(getent group docker | cut -d: -f3) -t vboxsf active /media/sf_active
```

`tar cvf /media/sf_mcs/backup.tar .` fails - Protocol error, host device is exFat 
`tar cvf /media/sf_active/backup.tar .` works, host device is APFS

Answer (score 0):

Try [the solution by andrew.46](https://askubuntu.com/a/745016/953371) that suggests adding your user to the user-group of `vboxsf`.

- If you are still facing the problem that the folder is locked and you can't `cd` without being the root or similar then:
- On your Windows installation, **go to the shared folder and check if "read only" is not tick marked in folder properties**.

I had this issue which made me scratch my head for so long. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you can also umount your **shared file** and remount it again by:

```
sudo umount /media/sf_YOUR_SHARED_FOLDER
```

Then re-mount it, again;

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o gid=<usernameID>,uid=<groupID>,rw
<Shared_File_name> /media/<Shared_File_name> # mount vbox file
```

The idea from this, is to transfer the permission from your root to your Linux user.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your folder is not at least protected with a username as perhaps User or Administrator in Windows perhaps.

Make a new folder if the first folder didn't work. Make sure of rights in Windows.

As earlier said by Andrew try to add yourself to the group vboxsf